# Array out of function javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm doing an exercise for school in javascript, I've to simulate a 
booking system for flights.
To see who has already booked I created two boolean arrays ( one per class ) , and when you book the place I put it to false , the problem is that arrays aren't put to false...any solution?
and sorry for the bad english !

```
<script>
   var eco = [true, true, true, true, true];
   var pri = [true, true, true, true, true];
   function economica(n)
      {

        var cambiato = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            if (eco[i] == true) {
                switch (i) {
                    case 0: document.getElementById("e1").innerHTML = n; break;
                    case 1: document.getElementById("e2").innerHTML = n; break;
                    case 2: document.getElementById("e3").innerHTML = n; break;
                    case 3: document.getElementById("e4").innerHTML = n; break;
                    case 4: document.getElementById("e5").innerHTML = n; break;
                }
                cambiato = true;
                eco[i] == false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (cambiato == false)
        {
            if (confirm("Posti in classe economica esaurini \n Vuoi prenotare un posto in prima classe?") == true) {
                prima(n);
            } else {
                alert("Il prossimo volo parte tra 3 ore.")
            }


        }
    }

    function prima(n)
    {

        var cambiato = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            if (pri[i] == true) {
                switch (i) {
                    case 0: document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = n; break;
                    case 1: document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = n; break;
                    case 2: document.getElementById("p3").innerHTML = n; break;
                    case 3: document.getElementById("p4").innerHTML = n; break;
                    case 4: document.getElementById("p5").innerHTML = n; break;
                }
                cambiato = true;
                pri[i] == false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (cambiato == false) {
            if (confirm("Posti in classe economica esaurini \n Vuoi prenotare un posto in classe economica?") == true) {
                economica(n);
            } else {
                alert("Il prossimo volo parte tra 3 ore.")
            }
        }
    }

   function prenota()
   {
       var n=document.getElementById("n1").value;
       if (n == "")
           alert("Inserire un nome");
       else
       {
           var x=document.getElementById("set").selectedIndex;
           if (x == 0) {
               economica(n);    
           }
           else {
               prima(n);
           }
       }
   }
</script>
<body>
<center>
    <h2 style="color:red"> 
        Benvenuti al sistema di prenotazione<br />
    </h2>
    <form>


    Nome: <input type="text" id="n1" /> <br /><br />
    Classe: <select id="set">
                <option value="Economica" selected="selected">Economica</option>
                <option value="Prima">Prima</option>
            </select>
    <br /><br />
        <button type="button" onclick="prenota()">Prenota</button>
    <br /><br />
     <table id="tabe" border="1">
      <tr>
        <td id="t1" >Seat Number</td>
        <td id="t2">Name</td>       
        <td id="t3">Class</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>
            <span id="e1">Libero</span>
        </td>       
        <td>Economica</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td >
            <span id="e2">Libero</span>
        </td>       
        <td>Economica</td>
      </tr>
         <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>
            <span id="e3">Libero</span>
        </td>       
        <td>Economica</td>
      </tr>
         <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>
            <span id="e4">Libero</span>
        </td>       
        <td>Economica</td>
      </tr>
         <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>
            <span id="e5">Libero</span>
        </td>       
        <td>Economica</td>
      </tr>
         <tr>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>
            <span id="p1">Libero</span>
        </td>       
        <td>Prima</td>
      </tr>
         <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>
            <span id="p2">Libero</span>
        </td>       
        <td>Prima</td>
      </tr>
         <tr>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>
            <span id="p3">Libero</span>
        </td>       
        <td>Prima</td>
      </tr>
         <tr>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>
            <span id="p4">Libero</span>
        </td>       
        <td>Prima</td>
      </tr>
         <tr>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>
            <span id="p5">Libero</span>
        </td>       
        <td>Prima</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

</center>
</form>
```

Comment: For one you need 5 here: `for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) ` or give the spans a class and loop over document.querySelectorAll("spanclass") or just `if (pri[i] == true) {
                document.getElementById("p"+(i+1)).innerHTML = n; 
               }`

Comment: The repetitions in your code make my eyes bleed. Please factorise your code. You should have a single function for coach and first, and the switch does not deserve to live.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo causing this error:

```
eco[i] == false;
```

should be

```
eco[i] = false;
```

And the same error in your second function - DRY

You need to change the for loop condition as well, to `i < 5` or `i <=4`

Once again same error in both functions - DRY